# Can't upload app with MarketingCloudSDK 8.0.1 to TestFlight

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, mobilepush-ios

I'm having trouble uploading the app to TestFlight with the latest MarketingCloudSDK 8.0.1. I get the following errors:

```
ERROR ITMS-90685: CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.salesforce.marketingcloud.core' under the iOS application 'XXX.app'.
ERROR ITMS-90205: Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'XXX.app/Frameworks/MarketingCloudSDK.framework' contains disallowed nested bundles.
ERROR ITMS-90206: Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'XXX.app/Frameworks/MarketingCloudSDK.framework' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'.
```

It looks like MarketingCloudSDK.framework has nested SFMCSDK.framework and iTMSTransporter doesn't like it.

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/tree/8.0.1/MarketingCloudSDK/MarketingCloudSDK.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7_armv7s/MarketingCloudSDK.framework

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Researching this now.

Comment: Can You please share what is listed in the Target > General > Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content in respect to the MarketingCloud? Do You have old SDK pod attached as well? To run 8.0.1 You only need swift packages for the [MobilePush](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/tree/spm) Module and [SFMCSdk](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/sfmc-sdk-ios).

Comment: I've attached screenshot to the question. Old SDK is not attached.

Comment: I have the same issue. Any news on this?

Comment: I have the same issue with SDK 8.0.4 but another error message `
ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'XXX.app/MarketingCloudSDK.bundle/MarketingCloudSDK' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."
` Any update?